# C printing a void * buffer

Tags: c, printf, void-pointers

kay so this

```
void printPacketBuffer(void *buffer, unsigned int length)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    char *c;
    unsigned int limit = ( (length != 0)?length:PACKET_DATA );
    for (i=0; i<limit; i++) {
        c = (char *)(buffer+i);
        if ( *c != '\0' ) {
            printf("%c", *c);
        }
    }
}
```

is working but the following function short miss the last 14 bytes can't understand why ?!

```
void printPacket (void * buffer) {
    unsigned int size = getPacket_size(buffer);
    printf("\n***********\nNew Packet holding %d bytes of data\n***********\n", size);
    char *c;
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<size+2; i++) {
        c = (char *)(buffer+i);
        if ( *c != '\0' ) {
            printf("%c", *c);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nactual printing %d, i=%d\n", counter, i);
}
```

and here is the calls

```
printPacketBuffer(pbuffer+2, getPacket_size(pbuffer));
printPacket(pbuffer);
```

Comment: last 14 bytes = last 14 characters

Comment: Maybe there is a (possibly valid) `'\0'` in the buffer ?

Comment: i'm calling these two on the same buffer !

Comment: What is the value of `size = getPacket_size(buffer)` that is printed in `printPacket()`?

Comment: Oh well - no more guessing then - run it under a debugger and see what's *really* going on...

Comment: @cap10Ibrahim you are not using the same buffer, in `printPacketBuffer` call you are skipping two bytes.

Comment: that's true put see the loop in second start from i=2 
and they both start printing the same characters but the last one stop 14 bytes before the first

Comment: @TioPepe the problem was that I was skipping more than two bytes , see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i supposed that pbuffer+2 is the next address by two bytes but I was WRONG here's what was happening 
if bpuffer = 0x7fff2c03d8a0 the bpuffer + 2 = 0x7fff2c03d8b0
now to move to next 2 bytes location I used

```
void *temp = (char *)pbuffer+shift;
```

anyway the morale of the story is to work with bytes cast to unsigned char

```
void printPacket (void * buffer) {
    unsigned int size = getPacket_size(buffer);
    printf("\n***********\nNew Packet holding %d bytes of data %p\n***********\n", size, buffer);
    char *c;
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<size+2; i++) {
        c = (char *)buffer+i;
        if ( *c != '\0' ) {
            printf("%c", *c);
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            printf("NULL ");
        }
    }
}
```